# map and/or filter to only return a single element instead of list. HASKELL

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

The following function can use ONLY `map` and/or `filter`. No `fold/foldr` etc. The function should have the following signature and types: `apply::n f x` and it should apply f to x only `n times`. A bit more formally described, it looks like so: `apply n f x = f (f...(f x)...)`, where f is applied n times.

This is very easily achievable with map, but the problem is that map will take and return a list. And I want it to only take a single integer, transform it by f and then return that new integer.

I so far wrote this: (works by taking and returning a list)

```
apply::Int->(Int->Int)->[Int]->[Int]
apply n f x
 | n==1         =map f x
 | n>1          =apply (n-1) f (map f x)
 | otherwise    =x
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
main = do
print(apply 2 (*2) [3])
```

How can I modify this function, s.t it no longer takes and returns a list, but instead takes a single integer and returns the new modified integer? Thanks

Comment: 1. get rid of map; this will make the type `Int`; 2. consider that on the line where you call `apply` you only made sure `apply` is called `n` times - `f` is not called at all. But if `apply (n-1) ...` returns the result of applying `f` `n-1` times, how could you get `f` applied `n` times out of that?

Comment: You say you can only use `map`/`filter`, but not that you have to use either. Why not just write `apply n f x | n == 1 = f x | n>1 = apply (n-1) f (f x) | otherwise = x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `map` or `filter` for this. If you enter the realm of the list monad, there's no escape (if you can only use `filter` and `map`). Here's a very simple implementation you can study on:

```
apply :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
apply 0 _ = id
apply 1 f = f
apply n f = (apply (n - 1) f) . f
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b87d743e2834aca)

Answer (score 0):

```
apply 0 _ x =                        x
apply 1 f x =                      f x
apply 2 f x = apply 1 (fmap f f)     x
apply 3 f x = apply 1 (fmap f f) $ f x
apply 4 f x = apply 2 (fmap f f)     x
apply 5 f x = apply 2 (fmap f f) $ f x
```

See if you can generalize.

Pro tips:

1. forall f. `x` = `apply 0 (fmap f f) x` and `f x` = `apply 0 (fmap f f) $ f x`
2. If `f . g` is well-typed, then `fmap f g = f . g`.

Not sure why you need map / filter; perhaps rephrase the question?